# What is the antonym of "single minded"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Example sentence:

> However much in earnest he might be, he had
>   nothing of the single-mindedness that belongs to a fanatic. (221, *Nineteen Eighty-Four*)

The word "single-minded" seem to suggest a complete and one dimensional self-devotion to a single motivation. (Which is a great way of creating a boring antagonist if I ever saw one)

I am wondering what would be some of its antonym?

The following would **not** work:

- half-hearted
- lackadaisical

They would not work because they are specific to a certain action but does not characterize a person in general, and they show a lack of motivation, rather than a **diversity** of motivations.

Sentence to apply the word to:

> "You may very well think that I am a single-minded fanatic, but I am in fact just as complex and ___ as you are."

Comment: ***Scatterbrained? Intellectual magpie/butterfly?***

Comment: Obviously, the antonym of "single-minded" is [Zaphod Beeblebrox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaphod_Beeblebrox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a word that speaks of "a diversity of motivations".

Try *multifaceted*.

> **Multifaceted** *adjective*
>   2 Having many different aspects or features: *his extraordinary and multifaceted career*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/multifaceted)

Your sample sentence will then be:

> You may very well think that I am a single-minded fanatic, but I am in fact just as complex and *multifaceted* as you are.

Here's an example of actual use, found on the internet:

> Examining Motivation in Online Distance Learning Environments: Complex, Multifaceted, and Situation-Dependent
>   [- M Hartnett, A St. George and J Dron](http://www.irrodl.org/index.php/irrodl/article/view/1030/1954)

Answer (score 2):

> "You may very well think that I am a single-minded fanatic, but I am in fact just as complex and **conflicted** as you are."

While not a typical antonym, conflicted fit's your example sentence.

> con·flict
>
> verb
>
> past tense: **conflicted**; past participle: conflicted
>
> kənˈflikt,ˈkänˌflikt/
>
> be incompatible or at variance; clash.
>
> "parents' and children's interests sometimes conflict"
>
> synonyms:  clash, be incompatible, vary, be at odds, be in conflict, differ, diverge, disagree, contrast, collide
>
> "their interests sometimes conflict"
>
> contradictory, incompatible, inconsistent, irreconcilable, incongruous, contrary, opposite, opposing, antithetical, clashing, discordant, divergent;
>
> at odds
>
> "the two suspects gave conflicting stories"
>
> having or showing confused and mutually inconsistent feelings.
>
> adjective: conflicted
>
> "my feelings are so conflicted that I hardly know how to answer"
>
> [google: conflicted](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=conflicted%20definition)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, not sure how to answer,  I'm

> **of two minds**
>
> of two minds (about someone or something)
>
> Fig. holding conflicting opinions about someone or something; being undecided about someone or something. I am of two minds about whether I should go to the convention.
>
> [idioms.thefreedictionary.com: of two minds](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+two+minds)

Answer (score 0):

In 1948 when Orwell was writing the book, *broadminded* would have done, but I don’t hear it used anymore.

Comment: "Broad-minded" still seem to exist, but it doesn't mean what it might have meant anymore.

Comment: Merriam - Webster's short definition is "tolerant of varied views".  dictionary.com says "free from prejudice or bigotry".  I don't think I've heard it used in this millennium.  Do you know it with a different meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, ***muddle-minded***

> mentally confused : muddleheaded
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/muddle%E2%80%93minded)

Also, ***out of focus***

> *fig.* not concentrating on single issues
>
> [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/out%20of%20focus)

Answer (score 0):

Indecisive seems to be a good choice. When one is "single minded' they move forward with complete certainty.

When one is indecisive, they may not move forward at all.

Answer (score -1):

The term ***single-minded*** is a synonym of the following:

> ***determined**, committed, unswerving, unwavering, resolute, purposeful, devoted, dedicated, uncompromising, tireless, tenacious, persistent, indefatigable, dogged, pertinacious*

Look up any of the these words in an online thesaurus and you will also find its antonym(s). For instance, the following are antonyms of *determined*

> **Antonyms for determined:**
> *irresolute, weak-willed, pusillanimous, yielding, changeable, flexible, indefinite, soft, undecided, unfixed, hesitating, vacillating, wavering*

However, in the OP's example sentence, *single-minded* modifies the noun ***fanatic***, it would be highly unusual  to describe oneself as a  ‘wavering’ or ‘soft fanatic’. It also appears to me that the connotations for *fanatic* have become increasingly negative in recent years; in fact it is often used in connection with fundamentalism and acts of terrorism.

> - Senior cleric blasts mosque leader for praising terrorist fanatic ...
> - Dramatic moment robot checks the body of an ISIS fanatic for explosives after he was shot dead...
> - Israelis 'more prone to fanaticism and fundamentalism'
> - Despite the fact that fanaticism exists in world religions, there has been a strong tendency to associate Islam with fundamentalism and fanaticism.

Therefore I would employ any of the following antonyms for *fanatic*, which are: *[**moderate**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/moderate)*, and ***conservative***. If the OP wishes to emphasize the diametrical nature of the statement, I would suggest the adjective ***[tolerant](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tolerant?s=t)*** and any of its many synonyms: *open-minded, forbearing, broad-minded, liberal, unprejudiced, unbiased, patient, long-suffering, understanding, forgiving, charitable, lenient, indulgent, permissive, easygoing, lax, laid-back*. The majority of these would fit nicely in the blank.

> You may very well think that I am a single-minded fanatic, but I am in fact just as complex and **tolerant** as you are.

Source: *Roget's 21st Century Thesaurus, Third Edition*